# Why is my attempt to unpack a map resulting in `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I know that `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` occurs when we try to iterate over something which is not iterable. For example,

```
for x in 4:
    pass

m = map(str, 99)
```

In my case, I construct a map, and even though there is a problem, it doesn't fail until later. Something like the following line executes just fine

```
m = map(foo, [1, 2, 3])
```

The issue is with my function `foo`. Later, when I try to unpack the map-iterator, such as by writing `list(m)`, `foo` raises the `TypeError` I just can't figure out why.

```
import itertools    

def contains_iter(cont):
    """
    returns true if container is an iterator
                 or
                 if container is not an iterator
                 but container contains an iterator
                 or
                 if container is not an iterator
                 but container contains a container
                 which contains an iterator.
                 etc...
    """
    range_type = type(range(1))
    if hasattr(cont, "__next__") or isinstance(cont, range_type):
        return True
    try:
        for elem in cont:
            if elem == cont:
                # string "a" in "a"
                break
            if contains_iter(elem):
                return True
        r = False
    except TypeError:
        # object is not iterable
        r = False
    finally:
        pass
    return r

def deiter(it):
    status = contains_iter(it)
    if status:
        assert(hasattr(it, "__iter__"))
        mahp = map(deiter, it)
        tup = tuple(mahp)
        return tup
    return it


def print_io(inny):
    def outty(*args):
        args = deiter(args)
        try:
            output = inny(*args)
        except BaseException as exc:
            output = str(type(exc)) + str(exc)
        output = deiter(output)
        call_sig = "flatten" + str(args)
        output = "OUTPUT:  " + str(output)
        print(40*"#", call_sig, output, 40*"#", sep="\n")
        return
    return outty

class FlatClass:
    def __call__(self, *args):
        try:
            if len(args) <= 1:
                try:
                    r = iter(args[0])
                except BaseException:
                    r = args[0]
                    # if len(args) == 0
                    # `args[0]` raises
                    # exception
            else:
                args = map(self, args)
                r = itertools.chain(*args)
        except IndexError:
            r = tuple() # empty tuple
        finally:
            pass
        return r

flatten = print_io(FlatClass())

flatten(1, [2])
```

Comment: What's the exact error with trace?

Comment: This code is pretty convoluted, and it's unclear what the goal of any of this was. What were you trying to do? (If this is simplified code that no longer does what you were originally trying to do, then it seems like you probably could have simplified it further while still reproducing the error.)

Comment: Also, `finally: pass` is entirely pointless.

Comment: Your function is incorrect, by the way. a `range` object is not an iterator, to check if something is an iterator, you need to check for having both `__next__` and `__iter__`, and there's a lot of strange convoluted stuff going on... like, what in the world is `if elem == cont:` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The purpose of `elem == cont` is to check if the iterable is a string. `iter(iter(iter(iter(iter(iter('a')))))) == iter('a')`. You do not want to recurse on the basis of `hasattr(obj, '__iter__')` as that will lead to an infinite loop with strings.

Comment: @ToothpickAnemone that isn't a good way to check for a string, and it will give you false-positives. The idiomatic, sane way is `isinstance(some_object, str)`

Answer (score 3):

You've got an `itertools.chain` call that's trying to chain things that aren't iterables:

```
else:
    args = map(self, args)
    r = itertools.chain(*args)
```

Some of those arguments are integers. This isn't detected when the chain iterator is created, only when you eventually try to iterate over it.

With no idea what the goal of this code was, we can't say how to fix it. There are plenty of other parts of this code that are suspicious (ranges aren't iterators), purposeless (`finally: pass`), or needlessly convoluted (`range_type = type(range(1))` just sets `range_type = range`), and there are almost certainly more bugs, but this is the one causing the immediate problem.

Comment: The purpose of `finally: pass` is to set up a try-catch block (good practice) so that someone could add a `finally` or `except` clause in the future. Currently, no exceptions are caught, and `finally` does nothing, but that's because the code is in the early stages of development. Eventually, probably do want to put some code inside of the `finally` clause.

Comment: @ToothpickAnemone: But every `finally: pass` in the posted code is attached to a `try` that already has an `except`, so the `finally` isn't needed for the `try` to be valid. Also, anyone can trivially add a try-except without this setup; it does more to mislead and confuse readers than it does to actually make anything easier.